# ERROR:: --system is intended to be used for pre-existing Pipfile installation, not installation of specific packages. Aborting

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, pipenv, django-deployment

I finished my django project.And ı want to deploy my project on aws.I pulled from github my project and then on virtual computer on aws(ubuntu) run pipenv install,I am getting this error every time.

```
ERROR:: --system is intended to be used for pre-existing Pipfile installation, not installation of specific packages. Aborting.
```

How can I fix that

Comment: I had a similar problem, probably due to the fact that I accidentally removed the `Pipfile` configuration file.

Answer (score 17):

Please run this code.

```
pipenv --venv
```

A file directory is returned.This file is already collapsed by some reasons.
So you delete this file and you remake it.

In my case, this way solves my problem.

Comment: Took me an hour to find this - and 1 minute to solve the problem. Thank you!

Comment: This works, the above error means there ia already a similar project. Delete the directory that is returned.

Answer (score 13):

You can **get information about any running virtual environments** with

```
pipenv --venv
```

**To end a virtual environment**, run:

```
pipenv --rm
```

This solved the problem for me. Also, don't be afraid to leverage existing documentation with the `--help` tag.

Answer (score 5):

You can just remove the existing env,

```
pipenv --rm
```

and re-create the env

```
python3 -m pipenv shell
```

**Alternatively,** this works too: Come outside of the parent directory and create a folder there and create a virtual env in the new folder

```
python3 -m pipenv shell
```

Answer (score 2):

Appears there is a venv with a similar project name.
Either change the project name or
run the command:
pipenv --venv
delete the virtual env then run the command again
pipenv install django

Answer (score -1):

Please run it from the same sub folder the file is in or create the project by giving a dot(.) after the project name to avoid creating a sub folder. Else this issue would occur.